# What does the centered dot notation mean in the expression $|+\rangle|+\rangle\otimes(\cdot)$?

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, terminology-and-notation

In the expression $|+\rangle|+\rangle \otimes(\cdot)$, what does the centered dot represent? I have come across a definition of the centered dot previously, similar to the one given [here](https://machinelearning.wtf/math-notation/), but I am just querying to see if this means anything different in this context.

Edit:

This comes from the three qubit phase flip code in [Nielsen and Chaung](https://csis.pace.edu/%7Ectappert/cs837-19spring/QC-textbook.pdf), section 10.1.2, page 431. For this specific example, the measurement of $X_1X_2$ gives $+1$ for the state $|+\rangle|+\rangle \otimes(\cdot)$.

Comment: Does not seem possible to infer without a context. Perhaps $(\cdot)$ here just means anything (in the brackets)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read in the context of Nielsen and Chuang it's clear that $(\cdot)$ is acting as a [wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) for extra, dummy or unspecified qubits, as @NikitaNemkov hinted.

Quoting from my copy of N+C:

> ...Measurement of the observables $X_1X_2$ and $X_2X_3$ corresponds to comparing the *sign* of qubits one and two, and two and three, respectively, in the sense that measurement of $X_1X_2$, for example, gives $+1$ for states like $|+\rangle|+\rangle\otimes(\cdot)$ or $|-\rangle|-\rangle$, and $-1$ for states like $|+\rangle|-\rangle\otimes(\cdot)$ or $|-\rangle|+\rangle\otimes(\cdot)$.

The first two qubits are $X_1X_2$ while the other qubits (e.g. $X_3$) could be represented by $(\cdot)$.